# Wouldn't Bitcoin cause biased economy?

Tags: transactions, mining-pools, mining-theory

Whales, big miners, or those who hold huge amounts of bitcoin, if bitcoin becomes mainstream, won't big holders be like ultra rich people in today's world? Some holding lots of money, whereas some very less?

Comment: Uh, yes that's capitalism?

Comment: @RutgerVersteegden yes, I mean that. Will bitcoin mass adoption lead to capitalism as well?

Comment: We can hope. Free-market capitalism would be a lot better than the corporatism we have today, where rich people use the government as a tool to steal from regular people.
There's nothing wrong with some making more money than others. There's something wrong with the government stopping you from making money, or stopping you from competing with the rich, or taking your money and giving it to the rich.

Comment: Do you believe Bitcoin is intended to enforce some concept of equality?   Why should Bitcoin not represent the inequality that exists?

Comment: Why downvote? Can someone please explain

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but that's true of almost anything. People who successfully predict the future can leverage that into money. But they also incur the risk that they will guess wrong and lose money.

If, instead, bitcoin collapses, miners will find themselves with very expensive space heaters. And big holders will find that they have nothing at all.

Bitcoin is far from a sure thing. It could start a slow, steady slide down to $0 tomorrow. Or it could double in price next week.

Comment: Upvote: because you represent a picture which seems a lot more realistic than just being titled towards a particular side. I don't think anyone knows how things will unfold. Some people are bound to get right and some wrong.